# Insert and update into different tables in one Mysql query in php

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I've tried the code below but it didn't work:

```
if (isset($_POST['ubah'])) {
    $queryUpdate = mysqli_multi_query("INSERT INTO perbaikan SET id_perbaikan = '',idrusakbaik = '" . $id . "',komenrusak = '" . $_POST['komenrusak'] . "',tglbaik = '" . $tgl_sekarang . "'; UPDATE kerusakan SET  status = '" . $_POST['status'] . "'WHERE id_kerusakan = '" . $id . "'");

    if ($queryUpdate) {
        echo "<script> alert('Data Berhasil Disimpan'); location.href='index.php?hal=master/perbaikan-mekanik/list' </script>";
        exit; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Show what's inside `$_POST` array. Run `var_dump($_POST);`

Comment: What do you mean by "it didnt work"? Have you even tried to look up if the MySQL server threw an error? Additionally, be warned that your code is widely open to SQL injection

Comment: @NicoHaase ive tried to insert the mysql through phpmyadmin and it works, but when i input to php it didnt work, it means the query insert and update are didnt working

Comment: And have you tried to check for error messages? It happens from time to time that phpMyAdmin corrects invalid statements, while `mysqli_multi_query` does not

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as "two queries in one query". There are always **two queries**. and there is **not a single reason** to run them in one call. therefore just rewrite your query to two **prepared statements**

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO perbaikan SET id_perbaikan = '',idrusakbaik = ?,komenrusak = ?,tglbaik = ?";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("sss", $id, $_POST['komenrusak'],$tgl_sekarang);
$stmt->execute();

$sql = "UPDATE kerusakan SET  status = ? WHERE id_kerusakan = ?");
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $_POST['status'], $id);
$stmt->execute();
```